# is it possible to know when an hdd was manufactured using either smart features or not?

Tags: hard-drive, debian, external-drive

I got the following information from smart -

```
/home/shirish> sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb | grep Model                                                                                           [95%]
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M9T
Device Model:     ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD
```

Is there a way to find out when the drive was manufactued ?

Comment: This information typically is located on a label on the drive itself

Comment: Failing which, starting an RMA with Seagate will probably tell you if it's in warranty or not.